# Cannot Open Up in "Month" View using react-daterange-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-daterange-picker

How can we set `DateRangePicker` from the `@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker` package to show only months (i.e. like a month picker) when the component is first clicked?

Tried using

```
<DateRangePicker
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
    maxDetail="month"
    calendarIcon={null}
/>
```

but it is opening up in the "day" view

[image]

instead of the "month" view

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DateRangePicker options **maxDetail** value should be **"year"** instead of **"month"**.

```
<DateRangePicker
   onChange={onChange}
   value={value}
   maxDetail="year"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`maxDetail` default is already set to `month`. Since a month is composed (details) by days that's why you get that outcome.

In your case you need to set `maxDetail="year"`, given year details are composed by months:

```
<DateRangePicker
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
    maxDetail="year"
    calendarIcon={null}
/>
```